# Trouble with taking the derivative for neural network

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I tried taking the derivative for a neural network's sigmoid function below but I am getting a slightly different answer and I'm not sure why. I am trying to follow this blog's derivation: https://selbydavid.com/2018/01/09/neural-network/

I would like to take the derivative of the following with respect to $W_{out}$

$\hat y = \sigma(HW_{out}) $

where $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function $\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})}$

Note: H is a n x 6 matrix and $W_{out}$ is a 6 x 1 vector. This means that the derivative w.r.t. $W_{out}$ should be a n x 1 vector. $\hat y$ is also a n x 1 vector.

After trying to calculate the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{out}} \sigma(HW_{out})$, I ended up with:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{out}} \sigma(HW_{out})$ = $\sigma(HW_{out})(1-\sigma(HW_{out})H$

However, the correct answer should've been:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{out}} \sigma(HW_{out})$ = $H^T\sigma(HW_{out})(1-\sigma(HW_{out})$

I don't really understand where H transposed came from. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could walk me through this step-by-step. If it helps, I can post my hand-written derivation.

Comment: It comes from the chain rule for the gradient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Chain_rule

Comment: Please note that the blog you are reading employs **row** vectors instead of the more standard **column** vectors. Also $W$ is a matrix not a vector, while $H$ is a vector which includes the bias as its 1st component. Your focus on whether the vector term should be written as $H$ or $H^T$ is a distraction. The real problem is how to use matrix/vector notation to represent a 3rd order tensor, i.e. the derivative of a vector wrt a matrix. The blog doesn't address this issue adequately.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. How come **W** is a matrix? It has 6 rows and 1 column. And **H** has n rows and 6 columns, where the first column is the bias, how come this is a vector?

Comment: @BViz Looking at the blog section titled "Forward propagation" $W$ is defined as the "weight matrix" and $H$ is defined as $[\,1\,\,h\,]$ which is clearly a row vector. Maybe you've redefined these symbols for your own purposes, but $W$ is common in the literature, and is a good mnemonic for the weights.

Comment: `w2 <- as.matrix(rnorm(hidden + 1))`
I might be missing something obvious but this code creates w2 as a 6x1 matrix since hidden=5. And for his function feedforward:
`z1 <- cbind(1, x) %*% w1`
 here cbind(1, x) creates a column of 1's for the n sets of (x1 and x2) in the data set, which means this is of size n x 3. Following the code, cbind(1, h) (or H) is then of size n x 6. Does this mean H is still a vector and W is a matrix? And then it follows that dHW/dW is a 3rd order tensor? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I found the following papers rather helpful in getting a better understanding of this stuff, though the first two are more concerned with 2nd-order methods: https://nic.schraudolph.org/pubs/Schraudolph02.pdf, http://bcl.hamilton.ie/~barak/papers/nc-hessian.pdf and https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/learning-features-2009-TR.pdf

Comment: For posterity, those papers are: "Fast Curvature Matrix-Vector Products for Second-Order Gradient Descent" by Nic Schraudolph; "Fast Exact Multiplication by the Hessian" by Barak Pearlmutter; "Learning Multiple Layers of Features from Tiny Images" by Alexander Krizhevsky.  That last one isn't on neural networks but many of the techniques used in deriving weight updates overlap, particularly in the use of Bayes theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(W)=HW$. Then
$$
\nabla(\sigma\circ h) = (Dh)^T \nabla\sigma = H^T \nabla\sigma
$$
by using the [chain rule for the gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Chain_rule).

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for the help! Would it be possible if you could expand $\triangledown \sigma$ and show that equals $\sigma(HW_{out})(1-\sigma(HW_{out})$? What am I taking the gradient with respect to?